# No me arroja el resultado esperado

Tags: java

Necesito de su ayuda.

Soy nuevo en esto de java. Estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta.

Les cuento estoy tratando de hacer este ejercicio:

> En un restaurante especializado en huevos fritos con chorizo necesitan un
>   programa que les calcule cuántos platos de huevos con chorizo pueden
>   preparar con la cantidad de existencias disponibles en la cámara frigorífica.
>   Escribe los siguientes métodos:
>   constructor(int, double): recibirá el número de docenas de huevos y de
>   kilos de chorizo disponible en el frigorífico.
>   addHuevos(int): incrementa el número de docenas de huevos.
>   addChorizos(double): incrementa el número de kilos de chorizo.
>   getNumPlatos(): devuelvel el número de platos de huevos con chorizo
>   que se pueden ofrecer con las existencias actuales, teniendo en cuenta
>   que cada plato necesita una media de 2 huevos y 200 gramos de chorizo.
>   sirvePlato(): disminuye el número de huevos y de kilos de chorizo
>   porque se ha servido un plato (2 huevos menos y 200 gramos de chorizo
>   menos)
>   getHuevos(): devuelve el número de huevos (no de docenas) que quedan
>   en la cámara.
>   getChorizo(): devuelve el número de kilos de chorizo que quedan en la
>   cámara.

Voy bien pero:

**El Problema**

El método `sirvePlato()` no funciona según lo esperado.

**El resultado que esperado de el método `sirvePlato()` es**:

No me resta 2 a la cantidad de huevos total.
Al imprimir por pantalla me muestra el resultado en gramos, no en kg como lo pide.

Les dejo lo que llevo hecho

**Clase Restaurante**

```
public class ClaseRestaurante {

private int docenaHuevos; 
private double kilosChorizo;

public ClaseRestaurante(int docenaHuevos, double kilosChorizo){

    this.docenaHuevos = docenaHuevos;
    this.kilosChorizo = kilosChorizo;
}

//Getters

public int getHuevos(){
    return this.docenaHuevos * 12;
}

public double getChorizo(){

    return this.kilosChorizo;
}

// Setters

public void addHuevos(int numDocenas){
    this.docenaHuevos = this.docenaHuevos + numDocenas;
}

public void addChorizo(double cantKilosChori){
    this.kilosChorizo = this.kilosChorizo + cantKilosChori; 

}

// Metodos

public void sirvePlato(){
    this.docenaHuevos = (this.docenaHuevos * 12) - 2;

    this.kilosChorizo = (this.kilosChorizo * 1000) - 200;
}

public int getNumPlatos(int n1, double n2){

    int eleccion = 0;
    n1 = (this.docenaHuevos *12 )/2;
    n2 = (int)(this.kilosChorizo/0.2);

    if(n1 > n2){
        eleccion = (int) n2;
    }
    if (n2 > n1) {
       eleccion = n1;
    }
    if(n2 == n1){
        eleccion = n1;
    }
    return eleccion;
}
```

**Main**

```
public class MainRestaurante {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("PROBANDO CLASE RESTAURANTE");

    System.out.print("Escriba el numero de docenas de huevos: ");
    int docenaHue = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Escribe los kilos de chorizo: ");
    double kilosChori = sc.nextDouble();

    // Creacion de objeto
    ClaseRestaurante cr = new ClaseRestaurante(docenaHue, kilosChori);
    System.out.println("ESTADO INICIAL");
    System.out.println("Cantidad de huevos: " + cr.getHuevos());
    System.out.println("Cantidad de chorizo: " + cr.getChorizo());

    // Se añaden huevos y chorizo

    cr.addHuevos(1);
    cr.addChorizo(1.2);

    // Nuevo Estado 
    System.out.println("Huevos: " + cr.getHuevos());
    System.out.println("Chorizo: " + cr.getChorizo());

    System.out.println("Numeros de platos que se pueden servir: "
                        + cr.getNumPlatos(docenaHue, kilosChori));

    cr.sirvePlato();
    System.out.println("Cantidad de huevos: " + cr.getHuevos());
    System.out.println("Cantidad de chorizo: " + cr.getChorizo());

    cr.addHuevos(4);
    cr.addChorizo(1.2);

    System.out.println("Cantidad de huevos: " + cr.getHuevos());
    System.out.println("Cantidad de chorizo: " + cr.getChorizo()); 
}

}
```

**Esto me arroja como resultado por pantalla.**

```
PROBANDO CLASE RESTAURANTE
Escriba el numero de docenas de huevos: 2
Escribe los kilos de chorizo: 1,9
ESTADO INICIAL
Cantidad de huevos: 24
Cantidad de chorizo: 1.9
Huevos: 36
Chorizo: 3.0999999999999996
Numeros de platos que se pueden servir: 15
Cantidad de huevos: 408
Cantidad de chorizo: 2899.9999999999995
Cantidad de huevos: 456
Cantidad de chorizo: 2901.1999999999994 // Deberia arrojarme en kg
```

Comment: Gracias Kleith por hacer más facil de entender mi duda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.kilosChorizo = (this.kilosChorizo * 1000) - 200;
```

En esa linea al *kilosChorizo* que se crea en el objeto *ClaseRestaurante cr;* estas multiplicando por 1000 la cantidad de *kilosChorizo* parece una tontería pero al poner el *this.* estás modificando la propia variable del objeto, con lo cual todas las demás cosas que hagas con *kilosChorizo* también estarán multiplicadas por mil desde ese momento es mas, lo que añadas después de ese momento serán kilos y no gramos como pretendes, una opción es poner todos los chorizos en gramos y a la hora de devolver el valor desde el getter dividir por 1000 para sacar el número de kilos, de este modo no debería ocurrir.

Comment: Seguramente usando la división entre 1000 para mostrar en kilos cuando sea necesario o multiplicando por 1000 si te miden el dato en gramos, te sea mas fácil guardar en un solo formato en la variable de clase *kilosChorizo* más tarde.

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes en la funcion `sirvePlato`, revisa los cálculos que haces: estás asignando a `this.docenaHuevos = ( this.tocenaHuevos * 12) - 2` y esto no tiene sentido. Si tienes 2 docenas de huevos, la operación sería: (2 * 12) - 2 = 22 y eso se lo asignas a `this.docenaHuevos`. Ahora ya no tienes el número de docenas sino el número de huevos guardado en `this.docenaHuevos`. Y para los kilos lo mismo: Pasas los kilos que tienes a gramos al multiplicar por 1000, le restas los 200 gramos y guardas el resultado en gramos en la variable que tiene que guardar los kilos. Las variables deberían estar en gramos y en huevos no en kilos y docenas.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ClaseRestaurante {
//creo que el problema de tu código esta en el constructor
//en vez de docena de huevos tenes que pensar en unidad de huevos
private int unidadHuevos; 
private double kilosChorizo;

public ClaseRestaurante(int docenaHuevos, double kilosChorizo){
//a docena de huevos la paso a unidades de huevos 
this.unidadHuevos = docenaHuevos*12;
this.kilosChorizo = kilosChorizo;
}

public void sirvePlato(){
 //ahora que tengo unidades las resto directamente
 this.docenaHuevos = this.docenaHuevos - 2;
 // a los chorizos en vez de restar gramos pasalo a kilos 200g =0.2Kg
 this.kilosChorizo = this.kilosChorizo  - 0.2;
} 
/*
*el getHuevos() lo devolves directamente y el addHuevos los agregas*12
*/
}
/*
*Este ejercicio lo que enseña pidiendote que el constructor pida los
*huevos por docena y los tengas que usar con unidades, es la
*abtraccion y el encapsulamiento.
*Si observas cuando declaras al atributo huevos, antepones private
*(encapsulamiento) de forma tal que el cliente (el que usa esa clase)
*no puede acceder al atributo huevos la unica forma que tiene de 
*saber cuantos huevos tiene es mediante getHuevos()(abstraccion)
*el cliente se hace un programa con tu calse usando los getters y los
*setters; mañana se te ocurre sacar los atributos huevos y chorizo
*y los cambias por private Frigorifico frigorifico;
*y entonces modificas a getHuevos(){ 
* return frigorifico.getCantidadDeHuevos();  } esto es; el metodo
*getCantidadDeHuevos() de la clase frigorifico, y el cliente no tiene
*que modificar nada, pq pidio huevos y le diste huevos
*las clases deben ser programadas de tal forma que sean una caja negra
*el cliente sabe lo que hace pero no sabe como lo hace.  
*/
```

Comment: Hola Sergio, gracias por darte el tiempo de responder.
Queria preguntarte porque debo hacer la conversion en el constructor. A lo que voy es que me hubiera gustado hacerlo directo con las docenas y hacer la conversion en algun getter o un método.

Comment: lo que sucede es que si vos tenes en los atributos los huevos en docenas: private int docenaHuevos; entonces inicias con 1 docena, luego servís un plato lleva 2 huevos, entonces esa docena la pasas a 12 huevos le restas los 2 huevos y te quedan 10 huevos, si lo volves a pasar a docenas son aprox 0.83 docenas de huevos. y estas trabajando con enteros